# Exception when using DISTINCT clause with android content providers

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am getting exception when i am using below code.

```
String  contactId;  // contactId retrieved from Contacts content provider
private static final Uri        PURI  = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI; 
private static final String     PCID  = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID;
private static final String     PNUM  = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;
private static final String     PTYPE = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE;
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor puri = cr.query(PURI, new String[]{"DISTINCT "+PNUM, PTYPE}, PCID+"="+contactId, null, null);
```

If I remove `"DISTINCT "+` in above code it is working fine. But i need DISTINCT clause, how to solve this problem.

If anybody succeeded with this problem, Please provide solution to my problem.

Comment: "I am getting exception" - please append the exception stacktract to your question